# Add a child view controller with push animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller

So this is the hierarchy:

```
BaseViewController: UIViewController
... ParentViewController: BaseViewController (Embed In: UINavigationController).
...... ChildViewController1: UIViewController
...... ChildViewController2: UIViewController
...... ChildViewController3: UIViewController
...... ChildViewController4: UIViewController
............ ChildViewController5: UIViewController
```

Need Push/Pop Animation for `ChildViewController5`.

I have tried [iOS: Container view - animate push transition when changing child view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42121539/1603234) but this is not working for me as I don't have common view controllers.

Also, I have a common customized navigation bar created in `BaseViewController` and it's push/pop is handling inside the `ParentViewController`.

What is the best alternative to do this?